# Hide client hostname (Docker container ID) in title bar with remote X server connection

Tags: x11, docker, x-server, openbox

When running a GUI app in a Docker container I'm mapping the X11 socket to give the application access to the X server on the host like so:

```
docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix my_image
```

The issue is that by default the WM adds the hostname of the client, which is in my case the container's ID, to the title bar:
[image: Example of a dockerised window]

This ID adds no value to the user. Is there a way to get rid of the `(effbff37ddd9)` part?

We're using Openbox as the window manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the source code of Openbox I can conclude it isn't possible to hide the client name part because the logic is hardcoded in [client.c](https://github.com/danakj/openbox/blob/master/openbox/client.c#L2449):

```
if (strcmp(localhost, s) != 0)
    self->client_machine = s;
...
```

And then [here](https://github.com/danakj/openbox/blob/master/openbox/client.c#L2120):

```
if (self->client_machine) {
    visible = g_strdup_printf("%s (%s)", data, self->client_machine);
    g_free(data);
} ...
```

## Workaround

There is a workaround though. By providing the container with a sensible hostname one can make it at least less annoying and, possibly, more useful for the user:

```
docker run ... -h my-app ...
```

The result:

[image]